# Display info on ItemPage WITHOUT using SelectedIndex from ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

## Problem

I'm trying to display information about a specific item selected from a `ListBox`. The items are from a Azure Mobile Services SQL Database. I've tried to capture the `SelectedIndex` and then query the database where the `RowID` equals the `SelectedIndex`. Unfortunately, the user is given the option to sort the data therefore changing the ID of the items to where they no longer match their `RowID` from the database.

### Code from Main.xaml

```
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="10,97,12,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" Margin="10,10,-12,0" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

---

Now would it be possible to somehow capture the value of `FirstName` and `LastName` and then query the database based on those values?

### Update - Code from Item.xaml

```
private MobileServiceCollection<Phones, Phones> items;
    private IMobileServiceTable<Phones> phoneTable =
        App.MobileService.GetTable<Phones>();

    public PhoneItemView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var listItem = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Phones;                        
        string selectedIndex = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out selectedIndex))
        {
            //Start progressBar
            progressBar1.IsEnabled = true;
            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

            //Query database
            try
            {
                items = await phoneTable
                   .Where(phone => phone.Model == listItem.Model)
                   .ToCollectionAsync();
            }
            catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            }

            MainListBox.ItemsSource = items;

            //End progressBar
            progressBar1.IsEnabled = false;
            progressBar1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
    }
```

On the `Main.xaml` page when an item is selected from the `MainListBox` the `SelectedItem` property is then passed to the Item.xaml page as it can be seen above. That is then used to query the database. Is this correct?

### Edit 2

```
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,  SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewModels/Phones/PhoneItemView.xaml?selectedItem=" + MainListBox.SelectedItem, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: If you're running the code on the OnNavigatedTo event, the list likely doesn't have any item selected, so the `listItem` will likely be null.

Comment: @carlosfigueira well the value should be passed to it from `Main.xaml` shown above in edit 2.

Comment: You're the best person to tell whether the value is there or not - you have that information on your debugger. When you get the NullReferenceException, in which line does it happen? Which object is null?

Comment: [ExceptionMessage]:[Input string was not in a correct format.]
[StackTrace]:[
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Convert.ToInt32(String value)
   at WPTracker.ViewModels.Phones.PhoneItemView.<OnNavigatedTo>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change it to be more like this

App.xaml.cs

```
public static Phones SelectedPhone { get; set; }
```

Selection

```
private void MainListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender,  SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    App.SelectedPhone = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Phones;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewModels/Phones/PhoneItemView.xaml, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

OnNavigatedTo

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    var listItem = App.SelectedPhone;
    progressBar1.IsEnabled = true;
    progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = true;

    //Query database
    try
    {
        items = await phoneTable
                .Where(phone => phone.Model == listItem.Model)
                .ToCollectionAsync();
     }
     catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
     }

     MainListBox.ItemsSource = items;

     //End progressBar
     progressBar1.IsEnabled = false;
     progressBar1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
     progressBar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

Comment: I've updated my code with you suggestion, but now I'm recieveing this error.

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'WPTracker.ViewModels.Phones.Phones'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Could you tell me on which function or which code line is causing that?


If it's this line
App.SelectedPhone = MainListBox.SelectedItem;
Then just change it into
App.SelectedPhone = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Phones;

Comment: I changed `App.SelectedPhone = MainListBox.SelectedItem;` to ``App.SelectedPhone = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Phones;` and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of capturing the `SelectedIndex`, get the `SelectedItem`, which should be an object with the properties `FirstName` and `LastName` (likely some class you defined). From there, you can query the database using those values. Something similar to the code below:

```
var listItem = MainListBox.SelectedItem as Person;
var table = MobileService.GetTable<Person>();
var serverItem = (await table
   .Where(p => p.FirstName == listItem.FirstName && p.LastName == listItem.LastName)
   .ToEnumerableAsync())
   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Ok, here is a copy of the code that I have. I keep getting an error saying "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" I updated it above.